# complete action using dialog in adview

Tags: android, admob, dialog

I am having a strange problem with Adview. I was checking my android code on device and when I clicked on Adview banner, I got "Complete Action using" dialog box. But now, when I tried to open the app again, it got struck at "complete action using" dialog box.
I searched stackoverflow for last 1 hour but did not find any answer.
Below is the onCreate() of my Main activity

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ads_text);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And the Manifest for Adview is

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent">
    </activity>
```

Hope to see a quick answer soon. Thnaks!

Comment: where is the manifest?

Comment: Forgot to paste that. Added now

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what options were in your "Complete Action using" dialog, but I suspect it will be a couple of web browsers.

This is entirely normal. When an app provides an Action Intent to the Android framework for actioning, if the Android framework has more than one app that could complete the Action (and no default has yet been selected) then it prompts the user for which app to use.

It sounds like you have installed an app that has declared that it can respond to View URL Intents. SO you are getting that app along with your std browser being offered as consumers.

Nothing to see here. Move along.

Comment: Yes, They are mostly browsers. But the problem is, when I tried to resume the app again, It again sent me that complete action using dialog.

Comment: When the dialog first appears did you choose and option? If not the Intent will be on your application Task stack and will be shown again.